# Install Vanilla Wordpress to Drupal to use Vanilla Forum

Tags: 7

any one knows how to install vanilla forum to drupal. I try to search a good article but could not success.I need step by step to do this.

Comment: Wordpress and Drupal are completely separate CMS. You don't install Wordpress on Drupal, you install both on your webserver. Can you clarify what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: requirement says to install vanilla wordpress install to drupal. I believe it vanilla forum.

Comment: yep. I want to know how to add this to Drupal project and how ti use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to install [Orchid](https://drupal.org/project/orchid). Only by using this module you can integrate Drupal with Vannila Forum.

Comment: i have successfully install the module and try to follow the guide in https://drupal.org/node/1117992. It seems I didn't get the consept behind this. How do I install Vanilla forum and  jsconnect plugin to the drupal site. currently i'm running aquia drupal one